# "Play" sounds into a .wav

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, wav, midi

I'm trying to make a program that can convert ORG files into WAV files directly. The ORG format is similar to MIDI, in the sense that it is a list of "instructions" about when and how to play specific instruments, and a program plays these instruments for it to create the song.

However, as I said, I want to generate a WAV directly, instead of just playing the ORG. So, in a sense, I want to "play" the sounds into a WAV. I do know the WAV format and have created some files from raw PCM samples, but this isn't as simple.

The sounds generated by the ORG come from a bunch of files containing WAV samples I have. They're mono, 8-bit samples should be played at 22050Hz. They're all under a second long, and the largest aren't more than 11KB. I would assume that to play them all after each other, I would simply put the samples into the WAV one after the other. It isn't that simple though, as the ORG can have up to 16 different instruments playing at once, and each note of each instrument also has a pan (i.e. a balance, allowing stereo sound). What's more, each ORG has its own tempo (i.e. milliseconds between each point a sound can be played), and some sounds may be longer than this tempo, which means that two sounds on the same instrument can overlap. For instance, a note plays on an instrument, 90 milliseconds later the same note plays on the same instrument, but the first not hasn't finished, hence the first note plays into the second.

I just thought to explain all of that to be sure the situation is clear. In any case, I'd basically like to know how I would go about converting or "playing" an ORG (or if you like, a MIDI (since they're essentially the same)) into a WAV. As I mentioned each note does have a pan/balance, so the WAV would also need to be stereo.

If it matters at all, I'll be doing this in ActionScript 3.0 in FlashDevelop. I don't need any code (as that would be asking someone to do the work for me), but I just want to know how I would go about doing this correctly. An algorithm or two may be handy as well.

Comment: So, what you want to do essentially is a sampler and convert the output to a wav file, right?

Answer (score 0):

First let me say AS3 is not the best language to do these kind of things. Super collider would be a better and easier choice.

But if you want to do it in AS3 here's a general approach. I haven't tested any of it, this is pure theory.

First, put all your sounds into an array, and then find a way of matching the notes from your midi file to a position in the array.

I don't know the format of midi in depth, but I know the smallest value is a tick, and the length of a tick depends on the BPM. Here's the formula to calculate a midi tick: [Midi Ticks to Actual PlayBack Seconds !!! ( Midi Music)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038313/midi-ticks-to-actual-playback-seconds-midi-music)

Let's say your tick is 2ms in length. So now you have a base value. You can fill a `Vector` (like an `Array` but faster) with what happens at every tick. If nothing happens at a particular tick, then insert a null value.

Now the big problem is reading that `Vector`. It's a problem because the `Timer` class does not work at small values like 2ms. But what you can do is check the ellapsed time in ms since the app started using `getTimer()`. You can have some loop that will check the ellapsed time, and whenever you have 2ms more, you read the next index in the `Vector`. If there are notes on that index, you play the sounds. If not you wait for the next tick.

The problem with this, is that if a loop goes on for more than 15 seconds (I'm not sure of that value) Flash will think the program is not responding and will kill it. So you have to take care of that too, ending the loop and opening a new one before Flash kills your program.

Ok, so now you have sounds playing. You can record the sounds that flash is making (wavs, mp3, mic) with a library called Standing Wave 3.

https://github.com/maxl0rd/standingwave3

This is very theoretical... and I'm quite sure depending on the number of sounds you want to play you can freeze your program... but I hope it will help to get you going.

Comment: Thanks for your post. The problem is, I actually want to just write into a WAV directly. I do understand that playing and recording will do the trick, but I'd prefer not to have to play the entire song. There already is a program that can play ORGs and I could record songs with Audacity, but conversion directly to WAV would be "purer", and probably quicker. All the same, thanks for your suggestion.